# F# - On the parameters passed to C# methods - are they tuples or what?

Tags: c#, f#, parameters, tuples

I've read many times that

> Assemblies generated from F# or any other .NET language are (almost) indistinguishable.

I was then experimenting with F# and C# interop on .NET 4 (beta 2). I created a new solution, and a C# project, with the following class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static int Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
}
```

Then, on a F# project, after referencing the C# project, I tried:

```
MyClsas.Add(4, 5) |> printfn "%d" // prints 9 (no kidding!)
```

So far so good. Then another sentence I've read many times (perhaps on different books) came to my mind:

> When passing arguments to functions from other .NET libraries, you use a syntax like ".MethodName(parm1, parm2)", that is, the parameters are passed as a Tuple.

Add that to something that I've once read here on SO (but wasn't able find it to link to), on a question where the OP was trying to create a using like `[ 4, 5, 6 ]` (when he meant `[4; 5; 6]`):

> "Comma is the 'tuple creating operator', for everything else use semi-colon."

Then I modified my class to the following:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static int Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
    public static int Add(Tuple<int, int> a) { return a.Item1; }
}
```

Now I tried to use it on F#:

```
MyClass.Add(4, 5) |> printf "%d" // prints ... (keep reading!)
```

So, adding up the three quotations above, one can conclude that:

- F# will create a Tuple when it sees `(4, 5)`
- Then it will call the overload `Add(Tuple<int, int>)`
- So it will print 4

To my surprise, **it printed 9**. Isn't it interesting?

What is really happening here? The above quotations and this practical observations seems to be in contradiction. Can you justify F#'s "reasoning", and maybe pointing to some MSDN docs if possible?

Thanks!

### EDIT

(to add more information (from Blindy's answer))

If you do:

```
MyClass.Add((4, 5)) |> printfn "%d" // prints 9
```

F# calls the `Add(Tuple<int, int>)` overload.

However, if you create another F# project (so a different assembly) with this:

```
namespace MyFSharpNamespace
type MyFShapClass = class
    static member Add x y = x + y
    end
```

You can use it on C# like this

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    MyFSharpNamespace.MyFSharpClass.Add(4, 5);
}
```

So far so good. Now, when you try to use it from F# (from another project, another assembly), you have to do:

```
MyFSharpNamespace.MyFSharpClass.Add 4 5 |> printfn "%d"
```

If you pass the arguments as `(4, 5)` F# will not compile because `Add` is `int -> int -> int`, and not `(int * int) -> int`.

What is happening?!?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> When passing arguments to functions from other .NET libraries, you use a syntax like ".MethodName(parm1, parm2)", that is, the parameters are passed as a Tuple.

It's more hideous than that. See the description of method overload resolution strait from the [language spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc245030997).

What it says, basically, is that argument in a method invocation isn't really a tuple. It's a *syntactic* tuple, meaning a comma-separated list of something, but the parentheses are part of the method call syntax, and so are the commas. It's why, for example, `o.M(a=1, b=2)` isn't a method call with a tuple of two booleans, but rather two named arguments.

So, normally, every comma-separated component just maps to a distinct argument. Hence why `Add(1, 2)` calls `Add(int, int)` overload, and `Add((1, 2))` calls `Add(Tuple<int, int>)`. There is no ambiguity here.

However, a special case that kicks in for your particular case is this:

> If there are no named actual arguments, and there is only one candidate method in `M`, accepting only one non-optional argument, then the decomposition of `arg` to tuple form is ignored and there is one named actual `arg` which is `arg` itself.

So when you removed all overloads except for the tuple one, suddenly the entire thing inside the parentheses is effectively treated as a tuple constructor in a call. But if you'd e.g. have two overloads, `Add(int)` and `Add(Tuple<int,int>)`, then a call of the form `Add(1,2)` wouldn't resolve at all.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have F# installed right now, but it seems to me that

```
MyClass.Add(4, 5) |> printf "%d"
```

would print 9 whereas

```
MyClass.Add((4, 5)) |> printf "%d"
```

would print.. 4 right? Notice the double parantheses, the inner pair marking a tuple and the outer pair marking the function call.

Comment: Yes, I tested that before asking. But it is still strange if you consider the 3 quotations, isn't it? Were `Add` a static method of a class created by F#, that takes 2 parameters (and would be used as .Add(4, 5) from C#), F# wouldn't compile `.Add(4, 5)`.

Comment: The middle quote seems somewhat weird, but the last one fits fine with the double parantheses thing. Did you try removing the `Add(int,int)` declaration to see if it resolves to the tuple version then?

Comment: @Blindy: yes, if I remove `Add(int, int)` then F# will happily dispatch `.Add(4, 5)` to C#'s `Add(Tuple<int, int>)`.

Answer (score 3):

It's just compiler magic.

```
let add a b = a+b
```

`add` compiles down to `add(a,b)`, making it easy to call from C#. However, F# programs still see it as `add a b` due to an attribute in the IL.

When calling C# functions in F#, it may help to think of the C# function as having only one parameter -- a tuple, whose elements determine the correct overload.  So you can write:

```
// MyClass.Add(5,3) = 8
let eight = (5,3) |> MyClass.Add
```

Comment: How magic? "Magic"? Or "More Magic"? To me it is "more magic".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an F# expert, so I may be a bit off base, but I'd guess that the F# concept of a tuple doesn't correlate with the BCL `System.Tuple` type.  Tuples are a core tenet of F# and are built into the language, but C#, VB.NET, and most other .NET languages do not natively support tuples.  Since tuples can be useful in these languages, the library is gaining support for them.

I would further my supposition to say that an F# tuple is represented in memory in very much the same way that parameters are passed to methods in C# and friends.  That is, they are essentially value arrays of their components.  When this value array is pushed onto the stack for a method call, it would have the same effect as pushing each of its constituent components  onto the stack, just like when that method is called from C#.

So your second example creates an F# tuple, pushes it onto the stack, then calls the `Add` overload that takes the types contained within the tuple.

That's my guess, anyway.  Having presumably used F# more than I, you might have more insight beyond this.  You might also gain additional clues by looking at the generated code [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Comment: Hmmmm, very interesting. I will check the IL generated on many different combinations of F# calls to C# methods and C# calls to F# methods. Thanks!

Comment: This is wrong. F# tuple _is_ `System.Tuple`. The rest is incorrect conjecture based on the wrong premise.

Comment: @Pavel Minaev: I'm in the middle of some test now, and I have experimental observation that *seems* to contradicts you. I will post later, when I finish testing.

Comment: `printf "%A" ((1, 2).GetType())` is all you need to do to check it. That said, it does of course depends on .NET version - there's no `System.Tuple` prior to .NET 4, so F# running on 3.5 and below will have to use its own type. But, since the question mentions `Tuple` in C# code, it's clear this can only be .NET 4.