# How does the F# compiler know that a C# method is being called and that a syntactic tuple is needed for the parameters?

Tags: c#, f#

With reference to [F# - On the parameters passed to C# methods - are they tuples or what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025845/f-on-the-parameters-passed-to-c-sharp-methods-are-they-tuples-or-what), when calling a C# method from F#, the parameters are supplied as a syntactic tuple.

My understanding is that C# methods have to be called this way. So taking the example from that question,

```ml
MyClsas.Add(4, 5) |> printfn "%d"
```

works correctly, whereas

```ml
MyClsas.Add 4 5 |> printfn "%d"
```

will give the errors

```
This value is not a function and cannot be applied
This expression was expected to have type
  int * int    
but here has type
  int
```

My question therefore is, how does F# know that it's a C# method that is being called and that a syntactic tuple is required?

Comment: You can define such a function in F# too: `let foo (x, y) = x + y`. It's just a different type of signature

Comment: @AlexG, in your example, your are declaring foo to have just one parameter; whereas with the C# code, I'm declaring it as having two. Somehow, the F# compiler (appears to be) detecting that it's not an F# function though and so insists on a tuple, which must be then converted back to two parameters "under the hood". I'm seeking to understand how/why that happens.

Comment: I always assumed that C# methods were translated into tuple-ised functions and that there was no difference. I could be wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my F# extending the assembly metadata in order to support functional concepts. Consider this:

```
module MyModule =
    let curried x y z = x*y + z
    let tupled (x,y,z) = x*y + z
```

MyModule decompiled:

```
[CompilationArgumentCounts(new int[]
{
    1,
    1,
    1
})]
public static int curried(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return x * y + z;
}


public static int tupled(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return x * y + z;
}
```

So it seems F# adds additional metadata in form of attributes to help the F# compiler realize `curried` is different from `tupled`. But extending your C# methods with the CompiliationArgumentCounts doesn't work (I tried). It seems F# adds more metadata in the form of two assembly resources called `FSharpSignatureData.Curry` and `FSharpOptimizationData.Curry`.

C# doesn't know about this metadata and therefore the signature of `curried` and `tupled` is identical in C#.

A tip if you are the curious kind; download a good decompiler for .NET (there are many). By decompiling to IL or C# you often learn alot about how language features are actually implemented and what hidden costs they carry.

Comment: Thanks. This does rather beg the question, why does the F# do this, rather than using real, rather than syntactic, tuples and allowing currying of other language functions too? But I guess that's a whole new other question...

Comment: F# could interpret other .NET functions as curryable I guess, but since calling the function from C#/VB it would look like f(x,y,z) it would be natural to map them to x*y*z->w instead of x -> y -> z -> w. Check with @dsyme on twitter.

Answer (score 1):

This is because method calls to **non F# library cannot be curried**; in fact methods from non F# library behave as though they take a tuple of arguments. That's why you have to call a BCL methods passing parameters grouped in a tuple.

As I said it the comments currying happens at compilation of F# code. That means that compiler has ensured that every function has only one parameter, as required. So you can pass one by one parameter which is a partial application. From the decompiled code shown by @FuleSnabel we can see the attribute `Core.CompilationArgumentCountsAttribute`. On msdn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ee353833.aspx) you can read the following:

> Used internally by the compiler to indicate that a functions or member accepts a partial application of some of its arguments and returns a residual function.

Comment: OK, let's ask the question a different way: why can't they be curried? Since the CLR came first, with it's way of defining functions in IL, then came F#, what does F# do differently that means (a) it's functions can be curried and (b) the compiler knows when a function isn't an F# one and thus that it cannot?

Comment: From my undestanding, currying happens at compilation of F# code. That means that  compiler has ensured that every function has only one parameter, as required. So you can pass one by one parameter which is a partial application. As your BCL code is already compiled (for exemple with C# compiler) which doesn't do currying, you have to pass all arguments at once. That why this feature is just not available.

Comment: I think that tuple guarantees that all parameters will be passed to the BCL method but maybe there is another reason I'm not aware off